# Swift - Doesn't dataTaskWithURL terminated automatically after it gets the Data

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have spent 3 days to understand the reason for this problem.

I am successfully using the code below to get my data from server. But even though I can println() the data in the completion handler, the activity indicator stopAnimating() or label.text assignments happen around 20 seconds after the println.

I think somehow the session keeps alive after my data arrives. If so, how do I cancel it. If not so, what am I missing???

```
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(url)) { data, response, error in

           if(error == nil){

                 //This works in 1second
                 println("string coming from data")

                 //these happen around 20 mins after the above
                 self.loading.stopAnimating()
                 self.label.text = "string coming from data"
           }

    }
    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL` performs on a background thread. Always update UI on the main thread like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.loading.stopAnimating()
    self.label.text = "string coming from data"
}
```